# Where can I check if docusign have called my redirect URL after users have sign the documents? And where can I check if the url is correct?

Tags: docusignapi

On the API (Sandbox): After the users sign the documents. Docusign is redirecting to a REDIRECTING Url provided when I created the documents via the API. On My app, this action is not working. Docusign is not redirecting properly.
How can I check on the document or in the sandbox that docusign have redirect the users to right redirect url?

I have already manually call the link and the status in database works fine. So it's must be a setting in docusign or in my application. Any Ideal How can I make sure that docusign is receiving the correct redirect URL and call it?

Answer (score 0):

For Remote Signing, landing pages are controlled under Go to Admin > Branding > Destination URLs. More information on that is available here: https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-configure-branding

For Captive or Embedded signing, this is controlled by the `returnUrl` parameter in the call to request the signing session.

For PowerForms, this is controlled under Go to Admin > Signing Settings > In-Session Landing Pages

Comment: For Captive or Embedded signing, this is controlled by the returnUrl parameter in the call to request the signing session. - So there is nowhere to find out if this returnUrl was called or not?

Comment: That's correct - DocuSign doesn't log if the signer successfully navigated to the ReturnUrl or closed out of their browser / otherwise failed to navigate.